# bash script to echo wan ip

Tags: bash, osx

The following bash script is expected to echo the current ip of the wan, instead of google "what is my ip".
Error:

> ./ipChange.txt: line 2: +short: command not found
>   “??

```
#!/bin/bash
ip=dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com
echo “$ip”
```

Any idea how to fix it? Thx

Comment: See: [How to set a variable equal to the output from a command in Bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4651437/3776858)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
ip=dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com
```

by

```
ip=$(dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com)
```

Comment: Note for completeness: this seems to be IPv4-specific

Answer (score 2):

I have an easier oneliner for you:

```
curl ipecho.net/plain
```

If you want it in a variable:

```
myIp=$(curl ipecho.net/plain)
```

Comment: I think it's better to keep the OP's lightweight DNS-based approach instead of using a relatively more expensive HTTP request.